# Time delay estimation using crosscorrelation

Tags: matlab, fft, cross-correlation

I have two sensors seperated by some distance which receive a signal from a source. The signal in its pure form is a sine wave at a frequency of 17kHz. I want to estimate the TDOA between the two sensors. I am using crosscorrelation and below is my code

```
x1; % signal as recieved by sensor1
x2; % signal as recieved by sensor2
len = length(x1);
nfft = 2^nextpow2(2*len-1);
X1 = fft(x1);
X2 = fft(x2);
X = X1.*conj(X2);
m = ifft(X);
r = [m(end-len+1) m(1:len)];
[a,i] = max(r);
td = i - length(r)/2;
```

I am filtering my signals x1 and x2 by removing all frequencies below 17kHz.

I am having two problems with the above code:
1. With the sensors and source at the same place, I am getting different values of 'td' at each time. I am not sure what is wrong. Is it because of the noise? If so can anyone please provide a solution? I have read many papers and went through other questions on stackoverflow so please answer with code along with theory instead of just stating the theory.
2. The value of 'td' is sometimes not matching with the delay as calculated using xcorr. What am i doing wrong? Below is my code for td using xcorr

```
[xc,lags] = xcorr(x1,x2);
[m,i] = max(xc);
td = lags(i);
```

Comment: TDOA: Time Difference of Arrival

Comment: If you have the Communications Toolbox, you may use the function `finddelay`.

Comment: I am looking a solution through code using fft

Answer (score 2):

One problem you might have is the fact that you only use a single frequency. At `f = 17 kHz`, and an estimated speed-of-sound `v = 340 m/s` (I assume you use ultra-sound), the wavelength is `lambda = v / f = 2 cm`. This means that your length measurement has an **unambiguity range** of 2 cm (sorry, cannot find a good link, google yourself). This means that you already need to know your distance to better than 2 cm, before you can use the result of your measurement to refine the distance.

Think of it in another way: when taking the cross-correlation between two perfect sines, the result should be a 'comb' of peaks with spacing equal to the wavelength. If they overlap perfectly, and you displace one signal by one wavelength, they still overlap perfectly. This means that you first have to know which of these peaks is the right one, otherwise a different peak can be the highest every time purely by random noise. **Did you make a plot of the calculated cross-correlation before trying to blindly find the maximum?**

This problem is the same as in interferometry, where it is easy to measure small distance variations with a *resolution* smaller than a wavelength by measuring phase differences, but you have no idea about the absolute distance, since you do not know the absolute phase.

The solution to this is actually easy: let your source generate more frequencies. Even using (band-limited) white-noise should work without problems when calculating cross-correlations, and it removes the ambiguity problem. You should see the white noise as a collection of sines. The cross-correlation of each of them will generate a comb, but with different spacing. When adding all those combs together, they will add up significantly only in a single point, at the delay you are looking for!

Comment: I am a bit confused. Can you explain that solution part, where you say of generating multiple frequencies? Lets say i modify my source to, source=source+band_limited_noise; now when i do xcorr, i will get a comb of say 2 clusters of teeth, one of noise(this teeth is wide with low magnitude) and other of my actual wave(this teeth is narrow with high magnitude). How will this help me find delay? I am already getting this kind of curve when I plot cross-correlation result(yes, i am plotting it before finding the max)

Comment: I was trying to explain white noise as some sort of sum of its Fourier components, but forget about that. Anyhow, the xcorr of white noise is a single peak, as you want. The best way to understand this problem is to play with it in simulations. Just generate some white noise, some sines, or a combination, and calculate the autocorrelation (i.e. two signals with zero delay) and make a plot. You will probably see that result for the sines will have several peaks, while for the white noise, it has a single peak.

Comment: Ok. I changed my frequency from 17k to a few hunderd hz and now xcorr is working great. How can I make it work for 17khz? I read some papers but they are too complex for me. You mentioned something about source generating more frequencies. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

White Noise, Maximum Length Sequency or other non-periodic signals should be used as the test signal for time delay measurement using cross correleation. This is because non-periodic signals have only one cross correlation peak and there will be no ambiguity to determine the time delay. It is possible to use the burst type of periodic signals to do the job, but with degraded SNR. If you have to use a continuous periodic signal as the test signal, then you can only measure a time delay within one period of the periodic test signal. This should explain why, in your case, using lower frequency sine wave as the test signal works while using higher frequency sine wave does not.  This is demonstrated in these videos: https://youtu.be/L6YJqhbsuFY, https://youtu.be/7u1nSD0RlwY .